# Jaxb force attribute of inherited class to be unmarshalled first

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Apparently (for what i saw), jaxb unmarshall properties/elements in the order of implementation (the last setter is the last one called when unmarshalling).

And, still according to my observations, the setters/getters of an inherited class are called last (after the ones belonging to the mother class).

I'm in a situation where I do have to call a setter of my inherited class first.
Is there a way to do that other that overloading the getters and setters ?

I don't know if this matters but: I'm annotating my getter/setters ( @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY) )

Comment: it rather calls them in the order dictated by your xml format. Apart from that, it is hard to say what you are trying to achieve, post your code and xml.

Answer (score 0):

A JAXB (JSR-222) implementation doesn't provide a mechanism to guarantee the order in which setters are called.  In terms of implementation when the JAXB implementation makes use of a SAX or StAX parser then the setters will be called according to the order in which the elements are encountered.